# How to restrict right click option on the image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, right-click

I m designing my portfolio in ruby on rails. In order to restrict the image from being copied, i wanted to disable the right click and other features of copying an image from the website. How to do it?

Answer (score 3):

In most modern browsers you can disable the right-click menu for a particular image. To do so, you can use the event handler `oncontextmenu="return false;"` within the IMG tag that defines your image:

```
<IMG border=0 src="..." oncontextmenu="return false;">
```

For example, the context menu has been disabled for this image:

Note: In older browsers (e.g. Internet Explorer 4.x or earlier) this trick won't work. Also, the context menu will show up if the user has disabled JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

As all others already said: It's not possible in a reliable way. Only thing you can consider is to watermark your images.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly its not possible to stop people from copying an image on your page.

Simply disabling right click would not be enough, anyone could just view the source to see the image url

Comment: I meant its not possible to stop people copying the image

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the right click with javascript.

However, this is a pretty bad idea.

Since your images are sent to the browser of the visitor, they will be accessible, either by displaying the source or analyzing the HTTP requests, in the cache files, or simply screenshoting.

You should not break the user navigation by disabling the right click, your images will be copiable and there's nothing you can do about it. Deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.hypergurl.com/norightclick.html
This guy has mentioned that we can add a transparent gif image to restrict the copy function but i am not getting how to do it. I m displaying my images inside carousel. And carousel gets very tricky sometimes. Also ive uploaded my images in cloudinary so if a person can get the URL of an image then he needs certain parameters to access it which only the owner has.